# Sinatra query parameters

Tags: ruby, sinatra, instagram, instagram-api

Trying to get familiar with [sample Sinatra app](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) for the [Instagram Ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/instagram). The issue is that I can't find the correct way to apply arguments to queries, for example I'm trying to set the amount of posts being shown to **30**:

```
get "/user_recent_media" do
  client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
  user = client.user
  html =
  """
    <h1 align=\"center\">#{user.username}</h1>
  """
  for media_item in client.user_recent_media(self, options = {:count => 30})
    html << "<img src='#{media_item.images.low_resolution.url}'>"
  end
  html
end
```

I tried to apply the parameters this way but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Not sure exactly what your asking you can access params using the params object like so `params[:queryparam]`

Comment: user_recent_media(self, options = {:count => 30})

@ shaneqful I need to set the **count** parameter to 30 and it seems to be the incorrect way

Comment: @ShaneQful is right, try putting `count = (params.fetch :count, 30).to_i` (if 30 is your default and then `options = {:count => count}`. Then, any GET request made with a `count=20` in the querystring will then set the count to 20, without, it will be 30. See [the first section of the Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html).

Comment: What do you mean by “it doesn't seem to be working”? You need to include in your question what is happening and what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: @matt The default value was 20 and I was trying to set it to 30, however, the way I did it, it only caused a server error. (using heroku to deploy and test an app)